# Way to have multiple object from an enumeration class in an array or EnumSet

Tags: java, arrays, enums

i am trying to find a way to populate an array or some other data structure like the EnumSet with multiple object from that enum class. For example i have an enum class what contains for values like MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY. What i want to do it to find a way to populate the data structure with the those values multiple times.

Array or Enumset with [MONDAY, MONDAY, MONDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, TUESDAY, TUESDAY .....]

I have use the EnumSet already but i've been only able to fill it with each one of them.

Comment: Just use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Enum constants are just like regular static final variables referencing an enum instances. So you would create an array or a list just like with any other variable:

```
Day[] days = new Day[] {Day.MONDAY, Day.MONDAY, ...}
```

or

```
List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();
days.add(Day.MONDAY);
days.add(Day.MONDAY); 
...
```

The reason you can't have duplicates in an EnumSet is that a Set, by definition, is a collection that prevents duplicates.

Comment: I thought to use something similar like but i was afraid it wouldn't work. Another small question, say my enum has it's values like MONDAY(1) where 1 is a integer and it also has a constructor to initialize that value. When i'll make the list, will this value still be accessible? I've never used enumerations that much before so i am a bit lost..

Comment: An enum instance is an object, like all the other Java objects. Your list will contain these enum instances. So if your enum has, for example, a getIntValue() method which returns this int value, then you can call it to get this int value. Google for "Java enum tutorial", and read.